# Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ a null-set. Show that the subset $ \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x-y \in E \}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ a null-set. Show that the subset $ \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x-y \in E \}$ is measurable.
We already know that if E is a $G_\delta $ set the statement is true. and we want to use the following corollay: Let E $\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a set, then it exists H $\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a such that E $\subset H$ and $\lambda^* (E)= \lambda^*(H)$.

Comment: The function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y)=x-y$ is measurable, and your subset is $f^{-1}(E)$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest There is a terminological issue here, because in the context of real analysis the measurable functions are the ones such that preimage of a *Borel* set is Lebesgue-measurable. In other words, they are the measurable functions $(\Bbb R^n,\text{Lebesgue})\to (\Bbb R,\text{Borel})$, while measurable sets are strictly the Lebsegue-measurable ones. So "preimage of measurable is measurable" needs not hold, all the more if the set is is Lebesgue-negligible.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks for the comment, you have repaired a gap in my understanding of measure theory :)

Answer (score 5):

Consider the linear map $L:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$, $L(x,y)=(x+y,y)$. Then, your set $S$ is $L(E\times \Bbb R)=\bigcup_{y\in\Bbb R}(E+y)\times\{y\}$. Since $S$ is image of a Lebesgue-measurable set by a Lipschitz-continuous homeomorphism, it is measurable as well.

Comment: Thank for the anserw @G. Sassatelli  I agree with your proof, but I'm not sure about the last implication: $ \bigcup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} (E+y) \times \{y\}$ is an uncountable union of null-set, so how we can affirm that it's a null-set.

Comment: @Philip That identity is only to clarify that $L(E\times R)=S$. The reason why it is a null-set is that it is image of a null-set by a Lipschitz-continuous function. In fact, cover a null-set $K$ by balls such that their areas sum to $\varepsilon$. If $\lVert f(x)−f(y)\rVert<h\lVert x−y\rVert$ for all $x,y$, then the image of each of those balls is contained in some ball of radius $r'\le hr$. This provides a covering of $f(K)$ in balls the areas of which sum to at most $h^n\varepsilon$.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli how can you say that $E \times \mathbb{R}$ is in fact a null-set of $\mathbb{R}^2 $?

Comment: @userr777 It is a general fact that null-set times measurable set is a null-set. I thought you had it clear, since *you* went on to prove that $S$ is a null-set, while I had never actually mentioned in my answer (since you didn't ask).